# Apache2 server video streaming compatibility with mobile devices and PC

Tags: ios, apache, mobile, video-streaming, apache2.4

I am experiencing troubles trying some server admin and web dev stuffs, as I am a C/C++ dev...

What I want to do is to be able to view some videos, by accessing link like http://www.mywebsite.com/username/video_001.mp4
I am running an Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS server on a VPS Cloud from OVH.
I installed apache2 and put a .htpasswd file to restrict the access to specific valid user.
On my website *.conf* file, I then put some redirections to my videos folder :

```
Alias /username/ "/home/path/to/videos/username/"
<Directory "/home/path/to/videos/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require user username
    Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

My videos are MP4 / H.264, 1080p / 5fps, 1Mb/s bitrate formatted.

Everything **works fine** on Windows Chrome and Android (Chrome, Samsung browser).
But on iDevices, the player of the browser starts the video but displayes a black image for the duration of the video (tried iPhone and iPad with Safari, Chrome and Firefox / and on iMac, Safari and Chrome doesn't works, but I can download the video and view it using VLC not QuickTime).

I read somewhere that for compatibility reasons, I must keep the raw file and let the device/browser's player read it. That's why I don't really want to devlop a HTML5 player.

But, if I want to get the most compatibilty possible, what is the best solution ?

I thought I'd convert my *.mp4* file to *.ogv* and *.webm*, put everything in a directory, and make a small html page that will list the directory content, hidding non compatible files.
Like if I detect the HTTP_AGENT / browser, I'll know which file i'll put a like in my webpage (for example : for Android, my page will serve as an "Index Of", only displaying *.mp4* file / on iDevices something else).
But doesn't seems really reliable...

EDIT :
I discovered that the native video player inside iDevices and Windows Microsoft Edge **can't read** MP4 videos (1920x1072, 5fps, 1Mb/s) recorded using **openRTSP**. But, if I use **FFMPEG** to convert the file, it is **readable**.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the options of openRTSP, but I'd like to keep using it and not FFMPEG (we switched from it to resolve lot of artefacts).

Feel free to ask for complement !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos recorded with openRTSP are not playable on iDevices.
It seems that Live555 (openRTSP team) indicates it in its FAQ and has already transfered the information to Apple without any news.